# req.get('host'); giving a double domain

Tags: node.js, express

I currently have a problem with req.get('host'); It adds the domain twice for example mydomain.com/mydomain.com/account-duajHsj

```
const url = `${req.get('host')}/account-${created.id}`;
```

Comment: Can you please provide us with a minimal, reproducible example.
Use as little code as posible that still produces the same problem.
This includes that it is provides all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem in the question itself.
Test the code you're about to provide to make sure it reproduces the problem. I have added in my answer a minimal example that does not reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try `req.hostname` (http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.hostname) instead of `req.get('host')`

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am not able to reproduce your issue with my minimal example down here below:

```js
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);

app.use('/', function (req, res) {
  const url = `${req.get("host")}/hi`;

  // logs: localhost:4000/hi
  console.log(url);

  // logs: localhost:4000
  console.log(req.get('host'));
});

server.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port: ${4000}`);
});
```

I recommend that you create your own minimal example where the issue is recreated. For more information please read: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).